# How to unset a global variable?

Tags: php

```
    <?php 
echo "test";
     echo $city;
     ?>
```

This keeps echoing out the city from the url even though there is no other code
on the page.
I am assuming this is a global variable...

```
<?php
        unset($GLOBALS[_SERVER]);
        echo $city;
        ?>
```

I have started and destroyed a session to make sure is is not in a session. 
If I change the variable it will not echo out. 
If I change the url ?city=Boston to ?city=Chicago then it updates.

$city = $_GET["city"]; does not exist on the page...the rest of the page is empty.

Comment: That simple means you don't show us your entire code! Just show your **full** code! I think what you have is: `$city = $_GET["city"];` this in your code!

Comment: Not unless it is invisible. :)

Comment: `$city` was never defined! What output do you get from this script? Also add error reporting at the top of your file(s): `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and tell us if you get any errors

Comment: There are no errors displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely reason for `$city` already having a value is `register_globals` setting being `ON`. What it means that every `GET`, `POST` and some other variables are registered as global variables in your script. For example, if you open your script like `script.php?city=New+York`, you will have a variable `$city` defined in your code with value "New York".

If you don't want that behavior, you need to disable `register_globals` in your `php.ini`.

Read more about `register_globals` here http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 4):

The behavior that you're describing sounds like the PHP [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) configuration option is enabled. This option causes all GET and POST variables (as well as optionally cookies) to be created as global variables during script startup. This is a huge security issue, and as such has defaulted to being off since PHP 4.2.0 (released April 2002), and cannot be enabled at all in PHP 5.4 and later (released March 2012). The fact that it's on for your system is troubling, as it indicates that you are running PHP 5.3 or earlier, which is no longer receiving security patches!

To disable it, upgrade PHP to a supported version.

If this is not possible, edit your PHP configuration file, find the line where `register_globals = On` (or `= 1`) is being set, and remove it. This option has not been recommended for well over a decade; it should not be enabled.

(There is no safe way to disable `register_globals` at runtime. Disabling it using `ini_set()` doesn't work, as it takes effect before the script starts, and there is no way to safely remove all of the variables it creates, as it's sometimes possible for these variables to overwrite system globals. The only safe approach is to turn it off entirely.)

Comment: Wow if it really is this that's crazy, i've never heard anything about this. I didn't even knew that this is possible/existed.

Comment: Thanks...just using this server temporarily while developing...it is free with hosting.